# Using Python to select a specific toggle_link

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

The big goal is to find specific house bills.
With this code I am trying to select the link: `/legislation?q=%7B%22congress%22%3A%22113%22%2C%22chamber%22%3A%22House%22%7D` to narrow down my search to house bills.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://beta.congress.gov/legislation")) 

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    soup_links = link.get('href') 

import re   

r1 = re.compile(r'/legislation(\?\S+congress\S+chamber\S+House\S+)')
print r1.findall(soup_links)
```

When I do this I get an empty list instead of the link.

It isn't my regular express because the following works:

```
r2 = re.compile(r'\S+congress\S+chamber\S+House\S+')
newstring = '/legislation?q=%7B%22congress%22%3A%22113%22%2C%22chamber%22%3A%22House%22%7D'
print r2.findall(newstring)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are re-assigning a new value to `soup_links` each iteration; in the end only the *last* `href` attribute is assigned.

BeautifulSoup can do the searching for you:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://beta.congress.gov/legislation")) 

r1 = re.compile(r'/legislation(\?\S+congress\S+chamber\S+House\S+)')
soup_links = [l['href'] for l in soup.find_all('a', href=r1)]
print soup_links
```

This produces the one matching link:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib2
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://beta.congress.gov/legislation")) 
>>> r1 = re.compile(r'/legislation(\?\S+congress\S+chamber\S+House\S+)')
>>> [l['href'] for l in soup.find_all('a', href=r1)]
['/legislation?q=%7B%22congress%22%3A%22113%22%2C%22chamber%22%3A%22House%22%7D']
```

If you only expect *one* link to match, use `soup.find()` instead of `soup.find_all()`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://beta.congress.gov/legislation")) 

r1 = re.compile(r'/legislation(\?\S+congress\S+chamber\S+House\S+)')
soup_link = soup.find('a', href=r1)
print soup_link['href']
```